# What do we do about shared tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion

This popped up in a question earlier tonight:

Someone had a question about FPS (Frames per second) and used the FPS tag. The FPS tag, however, was a tag synonym of First Person Shooter (*also* abbreviated FPS).

In a case like this, what should be done with the tag synonyms?

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13146/permanently-show-fps-in-minecraft-beta) was the question in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing -- just retag.

Although, now that we've stopped using genre tagging, we *could* consider defaulting [fps](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fps) to [framerate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framerate)...

Comment: This was more of a question of "what should we do with the *tags*". Nuke the FPS tag entirely? That only works until the next 150 rep user comes along and accidentally recreates it.